# IIS URL Rewrite negation conditions set server variables

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-10

I'm trying to modify an long existing IIS Rewrite rule that adds a HTTPS Server Variable. It's causing me some problems when accessing an existing API from inside the load balancer on a virtual private network (i.e. inside the web farm). TLS is terminated at the load balancer so only HTTP is supported inside the network and I don’t want to upgrade those internal clients. I'm trying to add some negation conditions to exclude certain criteria. The rule currently looks like this:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SET_HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTPS" value="on" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The key conditions I'm looking at are as follows:

2. Where the `HTTPS` scheme is `OFF`
3. Where the `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to `HTTPS`
4. Where the `HTTP_HOST` matches a pattern that ends with `.localhost`
5. Where the `HTTP_HOST` matches a pattern that equals `localhost`

Point 4 is a nice to have because it lets me test this on my local development machine. Point 3 allows me to have intercommunication between APIs behind the load balancer. Point 2 aids me in identifying existing HTTPS connections that are coming via the load balancer, whilst point 1 shows me that the request came over HTTP rather than HTTPS.

I have designed a rule which I would expect to work, but doesn't. I assume I'm missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm testing it on IIS Express in VS2019 and I've added the following the applicationHost.config to allow this specific server variable inside the `system.webserver` node:

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTPS" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
</rewrite>
```

The non-functioning rule is currently:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SET_HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto}" pattern="https" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^[a-zA-Z-]+\.localhost$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^localhost$" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTPS" value="on" />
      </serverVariables>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It always 302 redirects me to HTTPS, so the last condition is being ignored when accessing http://localhost:1234 for example.

What am I missing? This rule has to work for IIS7 and IIS10. Is it the ordering maybe?

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: @DingPeng No way to do that on IIS Express though correct?

Comment: I think you can use FRT to see how the URL Rewite module handles requests.

Comment: That's standard IIS though, not IIS Express.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
<rule name="Set HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
       <add input="{HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto}" pattern="^HTTPS$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localhost$" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern=".*\.localhost$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

I use this exact ruling (excluding the HTTP_X_Forwarded_Proto condition) and it works like a charm.

PS: In a very rare case we have found is some custom web/url callers might populate the HTTP_HOST header with the server port. You should be able to sniff that out in a packet trace, and if this is the case you would adjust the HTTP_HOST condition to be a little bit more loose. (i.e. ^localhost$ would become ^localhost* or ^localhost:[0-9]+$ )